# Git Push no longer invokes "Compare & pull request" option on github repository landing page

Tags: git, github

Lately, whenever I run git push from the command line and I go to github to create a new pull request, the option ***never shows up***:

[image]

Instead I have to manually go into the the branches section and create a pull request there.

[image]

How can I get the "Create a new pull request" option back? I know the git push is working because I can still create pull requests, just not from the home page of the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the SSH key that you are pushing the branch with isn't associated with the GitHub account that you are opening Pull Requests with?

You can check the user that is associated with your SSH key by running `ssh -T git@github.com`.

Comment: I am still able to create pull requests, just not from the the repositories homepage.

Comment: It might not prompt you to create a pull request if it was pushed by a different account. You can check the user by running `ssh -T git@github.com`.

Comment: I executed the command and it authenticated me as the same user. But doing that the pull request option now shows up! Could you explain this behavior? I was pushing up to the remote before using the same computer and credentials and everything was just fine (I hadn't changed any settings or anything) and all of a sudden this behavior started occurring. appreciate the help!

Comment: Another thing to note: the SSH Key that was hooked to my computer said "last used with the last three weeks" and upon running that command it changed to "last used in the past hour".